# How to link specific library module into specific section?

Tags: linker, gnu, nios

I'm building a project on Altera Nios II soft core; as I'm using the new Max 10 that has on-chip flash, I would like to partition code into slow performance code (that run into on-chip flash, **.text**) and high performance code (that run into on-chip RAM tightly coupled, **.tight_instr**).

Using the `__attribute__((section(".tight_instr")))` directive I have accomplished the task of selecting functions to be linked into specific section, but, as such functions calls some libgcc modules, I would like to have also such modules into the same section.

I cannot link all libgcc modules into **.tight_instr** due to limited on-chip RAM, and having such modules into **.text** add a big penalty to the execution time.

What's the right way to script the SECTIONS linker?